# Difference in years between two Dates in Java 7

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, date-difference

I have a maven project in Liferay 6.2. There is a requirement in which I must compare an EndDate stored in Oracle DB and the current Date. In order to do so, I have created a scheduled job. I implemented the receive(Message message) method, which is the following one:

```
@Override
public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
    logger.info("Scheduler for checking dates on Penalties has started...");

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
    PenaltyService service = (PenaltyService)applicationContext.getBean("service");

    Date currentDate = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        currentDate = dateFormatter.parse(dateFormatter.format(new Date() ));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Current date is: " + currentDate);

    List<Penalty> penalties = service.findAll();
    for (Penalty penalty : penalties) {
        if (penalty.endDate == null) {
            System.out.println("No EndDate...");
        }
        else if (penalty.endDate.before(currentDate)) {
            penalty.setRevocationOrCompletion(1);
        }
        else if (penalty.endDate.compareTo(currentDate) == 0) {
            penalty.setRevocationOrCompletion(1);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------" + penalty.getEndDate() + " " + penalty.isRevocationOrCompletion());
    }        
}
```

I am having some difficulties in implementing the way to compare only the YEAR of those dates and check if the Difference between them is greater than 4.
Can you please help me sort this out? Any suggestion is really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not recommended for any application compiled with Java 8 or higher.  This code is only for Java 7

```
@SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )
int penaltyYear = penalty.endDate.getYear();
int currentYear = currentDate.getYear();
if ((penaltyYear + 4) < currentYear) {
    // Invoke penalty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. These supplanted the terrible date-time classes used in the Question.

Pull a `LocalDate` object from your database with a JDBC 4.2 driver. This class replaces `java.sql.Date`.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

If given a `java.sql.Date` object, convert using new methods added to the old classes.

```
LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;
```

Capturing the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. For example, it may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously still “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now() ;
```

Compare with methods on `LocalDate`: `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter`.

```
if( Objects.isNull( ld ) ) {…}
else if ( ld.isBefore( today ) {…}
else if ( ld.isEqual( today ) {…}
```

You asked:

> compare only the YEAR of those dates and check if the Difference between them is greater than 4.

```
int yearThen = ld.getYear() ;
int yearNow = ld.getYear() ;
if ( ( yearThen - yearNow ) > 4 ) {…}
```

By the way, your desired output string representing the value of the date object is defined in the ISO 8601 standard. That standard is used by default in the *java.time* classes. No need to define a custom formatting pattern.

The code in the Question has other problems.

Do not ask for the current date more than once. When crossing over to another date, the different calls could report different dates. Capture the current date once and use that `LocalDate` object repeatedly.

When you do not specify a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. So your call to `new java.sql.Date()` could vary in results when deployed. Better to specify explicitly your desired/expected time zone.